# Doubly linked list in C - Chain is breaking, not sure where

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a doubly linked list and printing it.

I have two functions, one that adds in the very front of the list and one that adds in the back. But it's not printing correctly.. I feel like I've messed something up and I know that there's something wrong with how I declare my next and previous pointers but I can't quite figure out what it is.. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

void initialize(struct list *l)
{
    l->head = NULL;
    l->tail = NULL;
}

void push_front(struct list *l, int value)
{
    if(l->head == NULL)
    {
        l->head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->head->prev = NULL;
        l->head->val = value;
        if(l->tail == NULL)
            l->head->next = l->tail;
    } else {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->head->prev = temp;
        temp->next = l->head;
        temp->val = value;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        l->head = temp;
    }
}

void push_back(struct list *l, int value)
{
    if(l->tail == NULL)
    {
        l->tail = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->tail->next = NULL;
        l->tail->val = value;
        if(l->head == NULL)
            l->tail->prev = l->head;
    } else {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = l->tail;
        temp->val = value;
        temp->next = NULL;
        l->tail = temp;
    }
}

void print(struct list *l)
{
    if(l->head == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", "List is empty..");
    } else {
        struct node *current;
        current = l->head;
        while(current != NULL)
         {
             printf("%d", current->val);
             current = current->next;
         }
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct list l;
    initialize(&l);

    push_front(&l, 6);
    push_front(&l, 7);
    push_back(&l, 10);
    push_front(&l, 8);
    push_front(&l, 9);
    push_back(&l, 11);

    print(&l);   


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least print a space on one side or the other of the number in the list, and a newline at the end would make sense.  What output do you get?  Have you tried printing after each operation (each `push_front()` or `push_back()`) to see where the trouble occurs?  Why not?  Electrons and photons on your screen are cheap?

Comment: With the way the functions are called, I get the following output:
9 8 7 6.

Comment: Apply standard debugging techniques. Use a debugger. Use debug print statements. Reduce your test code to the minimum, debug that case until it passes, then move on to the next more complicated test case and so on. Don't pick a random test case and then just throw your hands up in defeat when that fails. Be systematic and apply some rigour.

Answer (score 2):

Amongst other problems, your `push_front()` code doesn't ensure that `l->tail` is set.  It is:

```
void push_front(struct list *l, int value)
{
    if(l->head == NULL)
    {
        l->head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->head->prev = NULL;
        l->head->val = value;
        if(l->tail == NULL)
            l->head->next = l->tail;
    } else {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->head->prev = temp;
        temp->next = l->head;
        temp->val = value;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        l->head = temp;
    }
}
```

It should check that memory allocations succeed.  It should ensure that `l->tail` is set when `l->head` was null.  Etc.

```
void push_front(struct list *l, int value)
{
    struct node *node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == 0)
        err_error("Failed to allocate memory for a node\n"); // Does not return
    node->val = value;
    node->prev = NULL;

    if (l->head == NULL)
    {
        assert(l->tail == NULL);
        l->head = node;
        node->next = NULL;
        l->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        l->head->prev = node;
        node->next = l->head;
        l->head = node;
    }
}
```

Similar changes will be necessary in `push_back()`:

```
void push_back(struct list *l, int value)
{
    struct node *node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL)
        err_error("Failed to allocate memory for a node\n");  // Does not return
    node->val = value;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (l->tail == NULL)
    {
        assert(l->head == NULL);
        l->head = node;
        l->tail = node;
        node->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(l->tail->next == NULL);
        l->tail->next = node;
        node->prev = l->tail;
        l->tail = node;
    }
}
```

It would be worth have a `print_backwards()` and a `print_forwards()` function.  You can use them both after each operation to ensure that the lists make sense.  You can add a lot more assertions to make sure things make sense.

Revise `print()` and `main()`:

```
void print(struct list *l)
{
    if (l->head == NULL)
        printf("%s\n", "List is empty..");
    else
    {
        struct node *current;
        current = l->head;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            printf(" %2d", current->val);
            current = current->next;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct list l;
    initialize(&l);

    printf("Push front 6: ");
    push_front(&l, 6);
    print(&l);
    printf("Push front 7: ");
    push_front(&l, 7);
    print(&l);
    printf("Push back 10: ");
    push_back(&l, 10);
    print(&l);
    printf("Push front 8: ");
    push_front(&l, 8);
    print(&l);
    printf("Push front 9: ");
    push_front(&l, 9);
    print(&l);
    printf("Push back 11: ");
    push_back(&l, 11);

    print(&l);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Push front 6:   6
Push front 7:   7  6
Push back 10:   7  6 10
Push front 8:   8  7  6 10
Push front 9:   9  8  7  6 10
Push back 11:   9  8  7  6 10 11
```

That looks reasonable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no idea how I never set head and tail properly.

Answer (score 1):

You do not set `l->tail` and `l->head` in the following code blocks:

```
void push_front(struct list *l, int value)
{
    if(l->head == NULL)
    {    
        l->head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->head->prev = NULL;
        l->head->val = value;
        if(l->tail == NULL)
            l->head->next = l->tail;
    }

void push_back(struct list *l, int value)
{
    if(l->tail == NULL)
    {    
        l->tail = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        l->tail->next = NULL;
        l->tail->val = value;
        if(l->head == NULL)
            l->tail->prev = l->head;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I completely missed that.